# Ionic SumUp terminal payment callback not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, deep-linking, sumup-payments

I'm working on an **Ionic 4** app which have payment process using **SumUp**

I used **cordova-plugin-app-launcher** plugin to launch the app and it worked very fine, but the problem is the callback doesn't return to my app as they describe in this docs from **SumUp**
**https://github.com/sumup/sumup-android-api**

I'm using **ionic-plugin-deeplinks** plugin to catch the callback.

I have tried the deeplink externally and it worked correctly.

This is the params of deeplink.

```
    "URL_SCHEME": "com.unmeat.app",
    "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "https",
    "DEEPLINK_HOST": "result",
    "ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_2_HOST": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_3_SCHEME": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_3_HOST": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_4_SCHEME": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_4_HOST": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_5_SCHEME": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_5_HOST": " "
```

This is how i launch the SumUp App

```
this.options.uri = 'sumupmerchant://pay/1.0?affiliate-key=AFFILIATE_KEY&app-id=com.unmeat_test.app&total=22&currency=CHF&title=Test Order&receipt-mobilephone=&receipt-email=&callback=com.unmeat.app://result';
this.appLauncher.launch(this.options).then(success => {
  console.log('Success Launch', success);
}, error => {
  console.log('Fail Launch', error);
});
```

Can you guys help me please.

Thank